# Choose Default Out CHANNEL for OS X Audio

Tags: macos, audio

I need to get my default audio output to outputs 3/4 of my audio interface. What is the easiest way to do this? Do I need Soundflower (and will it even work)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but have you tried the Audio MIDI Setup? Its located in `Applications > Utilities > Audio MIDI Setup.app` Your USB audio device should be listed in the left hand pane and from there you may be able to route the audio as you wish

[image: Audio MIDI Setup window]

Comment: Thanks! I had been all around that box and tried everything. None of the output sliders work, for one thing. Hmmmmm.... Soundflower adds too much latency.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I managed to switch the default stereo output from channels 1/2 to 3/4 by using Audio MIDI Setup and then from “Configure Speakers…” I'd tick the second, rather than first, stream. Screenshot follows:

[image: Speaker Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Soundflower can do this easily (just tried it). Perhaps there is a way to do this with the built-in OS X stuff, though...